# Using HTTPS on a Amazon VPC connected to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

Ok, so I have a working Flask application on elastic beanstalk, and I need to have HTTPS running on it. I have it connected to a VPC which has an Elastic IP so my DNS can route to it.

I have successfully uploaded my HTTPS cert to IAM and added it to the load balancer for my app using the config section in the elastic beanstalk panel, but the problem is I have no idea how to apply it to the VPC.

Here's my current setup so you can understand why I'm having difficulties

```
domain on namecheap
        |
        |
Name server records are pointing to digital ocean
        |
        |
DNS A records on digital ocean ---> Various subdomains hosted on digital ocean
        |
        |
Subdomain pointing to elastic IP on VPC (want to add HTTPS here)
        |
        |
elastic IP pointing to elastic beanstalk env
        |
        |
load balancer which has cert (connecting directly here gives the cert)
        |
        |   (this connection is HTTP)
        |
       app
```

I don't really need end to end encryption, and I have a feeling that the cert should somehow be attached to the VPC and not to the load balancer. I have no idea how to do that though.

**Things I've tried**

- Connecting directly to the given auto generated domain for the env works but the cert is for my subdomain so I get a security error
- On the security groups section in VPC I have checked that port 443 is open for inbound and out bound traffic for the load balancer and the VPC security group

Comment: All you need to do is install it on the Elastic Load Balancer. There is no such thing as applying an SSL certificate to a VPC.  Your question really doesn't make any sense. What happens right now when you try to hit your load balancer with an HTTPS address? Does it not serve the SSL certificate?

Comment: No, the connection times out. Works fine on HTTP though.

Comment: @MarkB or did you mean when I hit the auto generated URL for the load balancer? I specified that in the OP.

Comment: Oh I see your problem, the domain name is pointing to an Elastic IP. This is not the correct way to use Elastic Beanstalk and won't work with the load balancer at all. The DNS record should be a CNAME pointing to the Elastic Load Balancer domain name. If you need it to be the root domain like "example.com" instead of a subdomain like "www.example.dom" then you will have to transfer the DNS from Digital Ocean to AWS Route53.

Comment: @MarkB That seems to have worked. Please post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the domain name is pointing to an Elastic IP. This is not the correct way to use Elastic Beanstalk and won't work with the load balancer at all. The DNS record should be a CNAME pointing to the Elastic Load Balancer domain name. If you need it to be the root domain like "example.com" instead of a subdomain like "www.example.dom" then you will have to transfer the DNS from Digital Ocean to AWS Route53